# Trying to call a value out of an array that is labeled as a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I had a diffrent api before this one. When i run the javascript I can get the array but when I try to append it to the table it tells me "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" I don't know if its because I'm trying to call back a number or what because it was working fine when i had a name value there. 
This is my javascript.

```
    var bitcoinApiUrl = "https://crossorigin.me/http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/weighted_prices.json";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").on("click", function(){
    var userCurrency = $('#userCurrency option:selected').text();
    $("#div1").append("<p id='currencylabel' />");
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: bitcoinApiUrl,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(currency) {
        // loop through currency
        for (var i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) 
        {
          if(currency[i].USD == userCurrency)
          {
              var $tr = $("<tr class='hello' />");
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i]['24h'] ));
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].latest_trade || "Information Unavailable") );
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].bid || "Information Unavailable") );
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].high || "Information Unavailable") );     
              $("#theTable tbody").append($tr);


          }
        }
        $("#currencylabel").append(userCurrency);
      }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: some `js` syntax issue.. Just click on the error and see where its redirecting you?

Comment: line 26 "$tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].7d || "Information Unavailable") );"

Comment: is it because it believes its a string ? or its for a function ? @GuruprasadRao

Comment: You have your answer I guess..

Comment: It just returns back empty though ? @GuruprasadRao

Comment: Can you post the sample response you receive?

Comment: So i just ran it again and I'm still having the same issue that nothing is pulling up i posted the entire code this is the whole api and I'm trying to return the last 7h 24h etc but it is not pulling down @GuruprasadRao

Comment: `console.log(currency)` inside `success` and see what you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: currency is not defined @GuruprasadRao

Comment: Do i not have the correct Reference ? @GuruprasadRao

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid:

```
$tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].7d || "Information Unavailable") );
```

You can't have `currency[i].7d`.  The property name can't start with a digit.  You can do this however:

```
$tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i]['7d'] || "Information Unavailable") );
```

Comment: that works for calling it but it still returns empty i don't know what I'm doing wrong @Yevgeniy Goyfman

Comment: I think your service is returning data in a format that you are not expecting.  The data looks like this: `{"USD": {"7d": "431.32", "30d": "436.23", "24h": "433.69"}, "IDR": {"7d": "5855746.41", "30d": "6021624.55", "24h": "5905382.85"}}` so your `currency` is not an array but an object.

Comment: Yeah i think you're right , so what would I have to do to correct this mistake i need to know the reference name wouldn't it be  `if(currency[i].USD == userCurrency)` @Yevgeniy Goyfman

Comment: just `currency.USD`  but I don't know what `userCurrency` is or what you are trying to do with that -- so it may not work as you expect.  I guess you are trying to see is `userCurrnecy` is equal to "USD", in that case, just do that and to access USD values do `currency.USD["7d"]` etc.

Comment: so this is correct `for (var i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) 
        {
          if(currency.USD == userCurrency)
          {`

Comment: `userCurrency` is a variable for a currency picker it works exactly like you said but i have different currencies as well if you looked at the object you saw that they all began with a different currency code so I'm trying to select it based on that @Yevgeniy Goyfman

Comment: No, if you are only trying to output USD data, just do: `if ("USD" in currency){var $tr = $("<tr class='hello' />");
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency["USD"]['24h'] )); ... }

Comment: I'm trying to output whatever currency is selected using the currency selector which is the var userCurrency @Yevgeniy Goyfman

Comment: so, really you want to do: `if (userCurrency in currency){var $tr = $("<tr class='hello' />"); $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[userCurrency]['24h'] )); ... }`

Comment: Right now i have `for (var i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) 
        {
          if (userCurrency in currency)
          {
              var $tr = $("<tr class='hello' />");
              $tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[userCurrency]['7d'] ));` this is my html for the currency picker `<label class="">
    <span class="">Pick a currency</span>
      <select id="userCurrency" style="display: inline; width: auto; vertical-align: inherit;">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option>JPY</option>
    <option>GBP</option>
    <option>CHF</option>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99882/discussion-between-yevgeniy-goyfman-and-villainy).

Comment: I'm still getting an empty append @Yevgeniy Goyfman is it the capitalization ?